# Heroku bootstrap navbar not rendering

Tags: javascript, css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, heroku

So... I have a rails app where I am using a bootstrap navbar. It all works locally on my machine but after pushing to Heroku it renders everything accept the navbar. [Take a look at the heroku site](https://www.littlerockbikepolo.com). Here is a [link to the github repo](https://github.com/eiei0/lrbp) if you need to reference it.

### Things I've tried

I've run `rake assets:precompile` with no luck. I've added `config/environments/production.rb` to `config.assets.compile = true` which I read was bad for performance but tried it anyways just to see if it would work (which it didn't).

I apologize if the answer is on another post... I just feel like I've looked through most of them and tried everything I could find. I'm obviously missing something. Thanks in advance for your help.

`view/layout/application.html.erb`

```
<!-- DOCTYPE -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

  <title>Little Rock Bike Polo</title>

  <!-- Meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <meta name="author" content="Jonathan MacDonald">

  <!-- Assets -->
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>

  <!-- Fonts -->
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Special+Elite' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

</head>

<body id="page-top" data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar-fixed-top">

  <!-- Navigation -->
  <nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top" roll="navigation">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="navbar-header page-scroll">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand page-scroll" href="#page-top"><img class="large" src="https://farm2.staticflickr.com/1478/24259118481_3bd44aea82_o.png"/></a>
      </div>

      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li class="hidden">
            <a class="page-scroll" href="#page-top"></a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a class="page-scroll" href="#about">About</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a class="page-scroll" href="#rules">Rules</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a class="page-scroll" href="#where">Where We Play</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Blog</a>
          </li>
          <li class="dropdown">
            <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Members<b class="caret"></b></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <% if current_user %> <!-- facebook login -->
                <li><%= link_to current_user.name, members_profile_path %></li>
                <li><%= link_to "Sign Out", sign_out_path, method: :delete %></li>
              <% else %>
                <li><%= link_to "auth/facebook" do %><%= "Sign In" %><% end %></li>
              <% end %>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.container -->
  </nav>

<%= yield %>

<!-- Footer -->
<div id="footer">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-12">
        <a target="_blank" href="https://twitter.com/lrbikepolo"><i class="fa fa-twitter fa-2x"></i></a>
        <a target="_blank" href="https://www.instagram.com/lrbikepolo"><i class="fa fa-instagram fa-2x"></i></a>
        <a target="_blank" href="https://www.facebook.com/lrbpolo"><i class="fa fa-facebook fa-2x"></i></a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

`assets/javascripts/application.js`

```
//= require main

// Nav logo resize animation
$(document).on("scroll",function(){
  if($(document).scrollTop()>50){
    $("img").removeClass("large").addClass("small");
  } else{
    $("img").removeClass("small").addClass("large");
  }
});

// About section toggle
$(function() {
    $('.accordion dd').filter(':nth-child(n+4)').hide();
    $('.accordion dl').on('click', 'dt', function() {
    $('.accordion dd').hide();
    $(this).siblings("dt").find("span").text("+");
    $(this).find("span").text("-");
    $(this).next().slideDown("slow");
  });
});
```

`assets/javascripts/main.js`

```
// Base
//= require base/bootstrap
//= require base/jquery
//= require base/jquery.easing.min.js
//= require base/scrolling-nav
//= require_tree .

// Coffee
//= require coffee/home
//= require coffee/members
//= require coffee/sessions
//= require coffee/welcome
```

### Heroku logs

```
2016-03-19T22:08:07.535722+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=www.littlerockbikepolo.com request_id=1b37aade-5d24-42df-bcf0-4a20e39fd5c3 fwd="17.27.100.166" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=11ms status=200 bytes=10449
2016-03-19T22:08:07.537387+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/" for 17.27.100.166 at 2016-03-19 22:08:07 +0000
2016-03-19T22:08:07.539314+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by WelcomeController#index as HTML
2016-03-19T22:08:07.540567+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered welcome/index.html.erb within layouts/application (0.1ms)
2016-03-19T22:08:07.541641+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 200 OK in 2ms (Views: 1.4ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
2016-03-19T22:08:07.818048+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/assets/application-52c2922bf3888faae91327ac966f10f93474a159ef20a14180eb9bd164ed87cf.css" host=www.littlerockbikepolo.com request_id=f27d91a6-fbba-4806-a52c-918053fe5ce4 fwd="17.27.100.166" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=11ms status=304 bytes=133
2016-03-19T22:08:07.819075+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/assets/application-f821fc720db642f34d4224d955f8fc0293316f4f0986691d662afa916da4d0d1.js" host=www.littlerockbikepolo.com request_id=6afa7af1-775c-4ab6-8e69-10869ebdfa8c fwd="17.27.100.166" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=5ms status=304 bytes=133
```

Comment: After deploy...what do your heroku logs look like...typically this happens because you have an error somewhere in your css. You can usually pluck that error out of the heroku logs.

Comment: The menu is there, but the styling is not applied. Have you tried to manually import Bootstrap (not via your CSS file)?

Comment: When I link to `/assets/base/bootstrap.css` in your `<head>` *before* the CSS gets linked, the menu works (as intended).

Comment: [Like this](https://github.com/eiei0/lrbp/blob/master/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb#L16) @Roy? If so... I deployed that change and its doing the same thing.

Comment: I added the logs above @toddmetheny.

Comment: @eiei0 No, I will post the solution as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this to solve the problem (add the `<link>` elements to your `<head>`):

```
<head>

<!-- Bootstrap first -->
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/assets/base/bootstrap.css"  type="text/css">

<!-- Your extra styling -->
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/assets/application-52c2922bf3888faae91327ac966f10f93474a159ef20a14180eb9bd164ed87cf.css" data-turbolinks-track="true" />

</head>
```

Your linking to `bootstrap.css` didn't work, because `<link <href='/assets/base/bootstrap.css'` is no valid code, see the `<` before `href`.

Comment: @eiei0 Glad it worked. Be sure to also implement `base/normalize.css` and `base/scrolling-nav.css` in the same way.

Comment: Question. Any idea why the asset pipeline wasn't importing those stylesheets? Like I said, it works normally when i run the rails server locally. Its only when I push to Heroku when I have the issue. @Roy

Comment: @eiei0 Hard to say as I don't know how that works or *should be* working. In your `application-.css` you try to import CSS at the bottom. Maybe it doesn't get there or catch it properly.

Comment: Well honestly, I hate to do this but that is what I need to know the most since it is a rails app. I'm now noticing that the viewport scaling is way off on mobile browsers too. I'm going to mark it as not answered just yet.

Comment: I think I've done just about everything in [this document](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails-4-asset-pipeline#dependencies-improperly-used). Driving me crazy!

Answer (score 1):

**Try this**

```
https://www.bootstrapcdn.com
```

I just include that links and this work fine for me.
For me that was good solution. 
Also I did -  1) rake assets:precompile; 2) config.assets.compile = true