# Bootstrap Navbar Missing on Heroku Deploy (NodeJS, Angular2)

Tags: css, node.js, twitter-bootstrap, angular, heroku

Before this is flagged as a duplicate question, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36103948/heroku-bootstrap-navbar-not-rendering) offers a ruby specific answer using rake which is not applicable in my situation.

Why is my bootstrap nav bar missing only in production despte no errors?

I have a NodeJS full stack application which I deploy to Heroku using their GitHub pipeline. I can verify that there are no errors in sending the Bootstrap js and css files. I can also verify that the the bootstrap navigation bar displays in my local environment and the code in both the local environment and deployed environment is the same.

- Production: https://a.udia.ca
- Github: https://github.com/udia-software/udia

Some of the answers I found online include referencing the bootstrap CDN directly, but bootstrap is loaded properly and I can see the html tags when I inspect the element on the page. Has anyone else run into this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Heroku tends to hold onto cached versions of your site. If you clear your browser's cache this should update the CSS that is rendering in the deployed environment